# Is git user.email public on github?

Tags: git, github, repository

I need to set user.name and user.email before commit. I want also upload my project to github.

In the past I have set user.name and this value is public on github website. The 2 values ( github username and git config user.name) can be different.

Because of the **git config user.name** value is public on github I think **git config user.email**  is also public on github website.

Is it recommend to set user.email to the same as github email? I don't want to be public my email.

Answer (score 0):

> If you'd like to keep your personal email address private, you can use a no-reply email address from GitHub as your commit email address. To use your noreply email address for commits you push from the command line, use that email address when you set your commit email address in Git. To use your noreply address for web-based Git operations, set your commit email address on GitHub and choose to Keep my email address private.

Refer: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address